# Separating contours of close objects (persons) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Is there any way to differentiate between contour of one person and two persons ?
I tried checking the area of contours, i.e. if the area is bigger than some value means two persons are in that blob, but the problem is when the objects come close to camera (which is still) and then get away from it, the size of the contours/blob changes accordingly and my threshold doesn't work.

P.S. I am trying to get single line trajectories for objects by finding the contours, find the center of them and track the centers.

Comment: It would be better if you give a little more details: are you working on frames of a video or you have just one image? Do the poses of the person changes or not (e.g they just walk)?

Comment: I would try person detection instead. Would that work for you?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Yes, I am working with videos of people walking. Do you have any method/algorithm for person detection in mind?